# Any reason UDFs would be faster that macro?

Tags: xlwings

I have a spreadsheet runs well using udfs but I wanted to be able to package it up so it is standalone. I converted it over to run as a macro instead and I noticed a huge slow down.
Is there any reason the UDFs should inherently faster or can I modify my spreadsheet to match the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default version of `RunPython` starts an external Python interpreter, executes the code, and shuts down the Python interpreter again. UDFs use a COM server that keeps on running until you quit Excel.

You can use a COM Server for `RunPython`, too, if you set `OPTIMIZED_CONNECTION = True` in the VBA settings, see [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/vba.html#settings).

Comment: Interesting. I had tried this else where and it didn't seem to do anything. I will experiment with it some more. Does `OPTIMIZED_CONNECTION = True` work with `RunFrozenPython` as well?

Comment: Good question. I don't think it currently works, but we should be able to make it work...maybe open an issue on GitHub?

Comment: I'll play with it some this afternoon and open an issue if it doesn't.